# Innodb Engine Semaphore Waits

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm not following exactly what i should take away from this wait information.I've been reading some guides and documentation but can't find anything about OS wait amounts and if this should be a reason for concern. We've had some slow inserts recently and am trying to track down a reason. This is mysql 5.7 running on an aws RDS instance.

```
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 60641802
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 72330127
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 99448631, OS waits 28947103
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 1297861775, OS waits 23786302
RW-sx spins 2795229, rounds 5258299, OS waits 4114
Spin rounds per wait: 99448631.00 RW-shared, 1297861775.00 RW-excl, 1.88 RW-sx
```

Comment: Let's see the queries -- both the obvious queries and any other queries touching the same tables.  Maybe we can approach it from that side.  Be sure to include `START TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT`, and the setting of `autocommit`.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
AWS RDS instance type?, Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.